# Оптимизация RecyclerView для галереи

Tags: android

Кто нибудь знает ссылки на статьи,  где описуются методы оптимизации списка для показа изображений. Сам по себе RecyclerView и GridLayoutManager плохо справляются.

Comment: И чем же они плохо справляются?

Comment: При быстром скроле тормозит и отображает одни картинки вместо других

Comment: значит вы что то не правильно делаете в реализации адептера или вьюхолдеров

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку Picasso для вывода фото. Перестанет тормозить. Если баг с отображением не тех фотографий останется, то добавьте в адаптер очистку imageview перед установкой картинки.